# How to remove edit tab after create commerce order

Tags: commerce

[image]

How to remove edit tab after create order for Authenticated User.

Comment: i think you should look at the permissions to edit own order

Comment: own order permissions is not work for edit tab.

Comment: other option is to make a custom template for that page  & then play with it. use hook theme suggestion for that ..

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the permissions for the user role in question. Doing so will mean they will not have access to edit orders, and only create them if you so choose to.

It might be a little easier to use the secure permissions module to manage the permissions in code.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Tab Tamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer) useful for that.

Comment: I have used tab tamer module. Tab Tamer module don't show edit tab.